# Sub groups within Group By query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is as follows

```
a | b
--|--
0 | 5
1 | 6
2 | 7
3 | 7
4 | 7
```

I want to sum over 'b' for groups (a = 0, a = 1, a >= 2).

Sample output should be something like,

```
sum | a
----|---
 5  | 0
 6  | 1
 21 | 2
```

What query should I be using?

Comment: Wait... the last two rows in your original table should have an `a` value of 2, right?

Comment: No Ray, it clearly says `a >= 2`

Comment: Whoa, going blind or something.... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should do it:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN a = 0 THEN '0'
WHEN a = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN a >= 2 THEN '2'
END AS anotherNameThanA,
SUM(b) AS `sum`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY anotherNameThanA
```

Comment: For SQL server you'd have to repeat the case statement in the group by - otherwise you'd end up with separate lines per value of 2 and above. Is this different in MySql?

Comment: @Rahul Edited my answer. It's important that the alias for the CASE..WHEN is different than the real column name. Tested it and it was a bit of a surprise for me, too, cause normally MySQL handles this pretty well.

Comment: @kaj Good thing is, he asked for MySQL :) At least he tagged it so. But you are right, so thanks for your comment.

Comment: one improvement on SQL server! +1